# How to see the whole ethereum blockchain deployed in localhost?

Tags: deployment, transactions, localhost, blockchain, ethereum

```
npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network localhost
```

I used this command to deploy. Now how do I get to see the whole ledger - all transactions  and everything?

I am new to blockchain. Hopefully, haven’t asked any wrong  question.
TIA

Answer (score 0):

[Ganache](https://trufflesuite.com/ganache/) GUI is an excellent way to see transactions, events and more

You will have to connect your local hardhat instance to this new local blockchain, keep in mind that you're losing benefits like JavaScript and Solidity stack traces, making debugging easier.

[Hardhat help page on this specific topic](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/docs/other-guides/ganache-tests)